# Building matrices using column vector and matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a column vector `A` (6x1) with values `[6 3 10 4 2 8]';` and a matrix `B` (6x5) with values

```
B = [1  2  3  0  4 ; 
     3  7  8  5  0 ; 
     0  9  1  0  1 ; 
     5  0  3  1  2 ;    
     4  6  7  6  4 ; 
     3  1  2  7  3]
```

I want to make five matrices with size 6x2 using Matlab.

- The first column is vector `A`
- The second column is columns from `B`, like `[A, B(first col)]`, `[A, B(second col)]`

  1. First matrix is `[6 1; 3 3; 10 0; 4 5; 2 4; 8 3];`
  2. 2nd matrix is `[6 2; 3 7; 10 9; 4 0; 2 6; 8 1]`
  3. ... and so on

Any help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop

```
C = NaN( size(B,1), 2, size(B,2) );
for ii = 1:size(B,2)
    C(:,:,ii) = [A, B(:,ii)];
end
```

This gives you a 3D array, where each slice in the 3rd dimension is a 6x2 matrix (for this example) as desired. You would access the nth slice with `C(:,:,n)`.

You can do this slightly more concisely with `arrayfun`, but it's basically a loop in disguise

```
C = arrayfun( @(ii) [A, B(:,ii)], 1:size(B,2), 'uni', 0 );
C = cat(3, C{:} );
```

You could omit the `cat` function if you're happy with results in a cell array, where you access the nth matrix with `C{n}`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  after doing some operations on C(:,:,ii),I get C(6,1,ii),  that is all the matrices will become a one column. I want to plot the values of the first row  C(6,1 ) and the other first row of  the ii matrices, how I can do so.

Comment: If this answer solved your original question then please mark it as accepted and ask a new question. Remember to include a [mcve] in the new question (similar to what you did here) so it is self-contained

Answer (score 0):

You could first make a copy of the columns of `A`, then concatenate `A` and `B`, and reshape:

```
At = repmat(A, 1, size(B,2));
C = reshape([At;B], 6, 2, []);
```

Or oneliner:

```
C = reshape([repmat(A, 1, size(B,2));B], 6, 2, []);
```

Then retrieve your matrices with `C(:,:,k)`

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this
```

1. `first_matrix=[A,B(:,1)];`
2. `second_matrix=[A,B(:,2)];`
3. `third_matrix=[A,B(:,3)];`
4. ... and so on